# How to sync SKAction

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have 2 nodes.

```
var leftGate = SKSpriteNode()
var rightGate = SKSpriteNode()
```

...

And I have some actions for this nodes.

```
var wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2, withRange: 5)
var moveLeftGate = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: 25, duration: 1)
var moveLeftGateBack = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: 0, duration: 1)
var sequenceForTheLeftGate = SKAction.sequence([moveLeftGate, moveLeftGateBack])
```

...

same code for the right gate

...

```
leftGate.run(sequenceForTheLeftGate)
rightGate.run(sequenceForTheRightGate)
```

...

Code works good. Random works good. But gates operate independently of each other. I understand why this happening. And I trying to understand how can I sync them? They must work at the same time...

Comment: Various possibilities, but a simple way would be to run the wait on one node, with a completion handler that then starts the open/close sequences for the two gates.

Comment: When you say they operate independently, I assume you mean the rotation. Is it a long way off or just a little bit? Could you not calculate (in update()) the angle for one gate based upon the angle (set by an SKAction) of the other gate?

Comment: bg2b, its a good idea. I tried before and its working good. But when I start adding repeatForever action, the problems starts. Perhaps I make some mistakes in the code...

Answer (score 0):

So... I solved the problem myself :)

We have 2 nodes (doors-gates), that should open at the same time at random times. My problem was that all the doors opened at different times despite the fact that I used same SKAction.

I had to figure out how to synchronize the operation of the gate so that the doors open at the same time, after the random time has been calculated. I solved the problem by enabling the nodes inside the function.

I create invisible node

```
var anyName = SKSpriteNode()
```

...some code (anyName set)...

```
addChild(anyName)

var wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2, withRange: 5)
var gateAnimation = SKAction.run(self.gateSync)
var gateAnimationSeq = SKAction.sequence([wait, gateAnimation])
var repeatAnimation = SKAction.repeatForever(gateAnimationSeq)

anyName.run(repeatAnimation)


func gateSync () {
leftGate.run(sequenceForTheLeftGate)
rightGate.run(sequenceForTheRightGate)
}
```

Sorry, if my English not very good(